# Regexp for "No symbols"

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I have huge log file. That has lines:

`FirstSecond
First Second
First    Second
First123Second
FirstSOMESHITSecond`

I found how to find with any numbers, text and spaces between First and Second. But is there way to search for first line in example `FirstSecond` which has no symbols between?

Comment: you make this *any numbers, text and spaces between First and Second* optional with `?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this sample:

```
First([0-9\sA-Z]{0,})Second
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6z8X43/1)